# typeset some unfamiliar math symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Can anyone here please help me to typeset the following math equation in LaTEX? [image] TBH, my problem is I just do not know the name of the symbols in the math equation, except "\rho" symbol. As such, I failed to find the other two symbols after almost an hour sifting through thousands of tiny symbols in *The Comprehensive LaTEX Symbol List* (1/19/17). Homefully, someone here will be able to help. Thank you.

Comment: `\mathfrak{M}`, which requires `\usepackage{amssymb}`; for the square root, use `\sqrt`: using `\surd` would make the formula like the original, but it's definitely very old-fashioned. Thus `$\mathfrak{M}_{r}=(-1)^{\rho}\sqrt{\mathfrac{M}_{11}\mathfrak{M}_{rr}}$.`

Comment: I use a lot the "\sqrt" math code, but I need a sqrt without the bar as shown on the picture. Is there a way to remove the bar on the "\sqrt". BTW, your 2nd "\mathfrac{M}_{11}" is incorrect. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment on the above *marked* as duplicate filed by egreg. I know the detexify free service. However, how does one draw a perfect figure presented by "\mathfrak{M}" in the field on the detexify site for it to recognize? OTOH, I tried to draw a "\sqrt" (without the bar) and detexify could not recognize it as a square root. Until then, I believe flagging this thread as **duplicate** and locked it down ain't help at all.

Comment: The suggested method is effective in most cases. I also added a comment about how to obtain the output. What else? [Here's `\surd` (click for picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yj4sJ.png) [Here's `\mathfrak{M}` (click for picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83zMV.png)

Comment: This is not a full proof solution. In other words, it may work for you, but it does not necessarily mean it would work for others. TBH and fair, I tried again several times and was able to duplicate for the '\surd' only once, but not the '\mathfrak{M}'. I strongly recommend that you remove the *duplication mark* and reopen the thread. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: If you add a minimal working example of what you tried so far, your question jumps to the reopening queue. As is, it is impossible to answer.